# Find a pattern with hole in it in a string python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to get and replace a specific pattern in which I don't know every character, from a larger string,
I have a string like that :

```
string = "data_table['something'][x] * a + b"
```

and I want to replace the part `"data_table['something'][x]"` of `string` into whatever I want, let's say `"my_thing"`, but I don't know what `'something'` and `x` are, it could be anything, I just know that `'something'` is a string, and `x` an integer.

I would like at the end to have `string = "my_thing * a + b"`.

I have a way to do it by reading the string in a loop, but I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it

Thank you !

Comment: Your question is really too vague

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you mean you want to extract `something` and `x` from a line of Python-ish source code, try running `import re;re.match(r"data_table\['(.*?)'\]\[(.*?)\]","data_table['hello'][83]=123")[1]` and also with `[2]` at the end. They should report back `hello` and `83` respectively.

Comment: I just edited my question for it to be more clear !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using [regular expression's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in python. The following code will do what you want:

```
import re
string = "data_table['something'][x] * a + b"
re.sub("data_table\[.*\]\[.*\]", "mything", string)
```

Which will give:

```
mything * a + b
```

The only downside here is that you will need to escape the square brackets, by putting backslashes ("\") around them since otherwise they will be interpreted as a regular expression construct. But since you say that only the `'something'` and `x` may change, you should be fine with the above.